# Create multiple tables using one query

Tags: mysql

I have a function building DB and creating tables if they don't exist, but it only works with one table. I have tried using "/", space and also ";" to separate the create table scripts, but none of them worked. Can you help me?
Here is my function:

```
private function buildDB() {

        $sql = <<<MySQL_QUERY
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(
                id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                title VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                slug VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                text LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                gallery LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
            );
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admins(
                id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                name VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT 'admin',
                password VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'
            )
MySQL_QUERY;

        return mysql_query($sql);

    }
```

Comment: execute two separate queries for both tables !

Comment: how can I return both queries then ?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    private function buildDB() {

            $sql =  "
                     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS projects(
                            id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            title VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                            slug VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                            text LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                            gallery LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci,
                            date timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
                        )
                        ";
            $sql1 =  "
                     CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS admins(
                            id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                            name VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT 'admin',
                            password VARCHAR(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_czech_ci DEFAULT '21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3'
                        )
                     ";

               mysql_query($sql) or die('Invalid query: <br/>'.$sql.' <br/>' . mysql_error());

               mysql_query($sql1) or die('Invalid query: <br/>'.$sql1.' <br/>' . mysql_error());

               //it would return errors if there are any, else 

       return "Tables projects and admins created successfully";
    }
```

Please be informed that mysql functions are deprecated and not recommended. USE MySQLi or PDO instead. have a reference from following queries.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php